# test set for time series forecasting

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, time-series, lstm

The example in the link below has a training and validation set from time series data. There is no mention of a test set. Why isn't there one and what would it entail to have one for a dataset whose time series data is being generated on the fly in real time?

I have 3hrs of data collected at 1s interval. I would like to predict the next 30 min before it becomes available. What should be the train/validate/test split look like? Can test set be skipped?

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **never** recommended to skip the test set. In the TensorFlow example, the purpose was to demonstrate how you can play with time series; you can test on the 'test set' just like you do with your validation, with the constraint that the test set is completely unknown: here we come to your second question.

With regard to the test set, in your use case, like you said, the test set is the data generated on the fly.

You can, of course, split your initial dataset into train/val/test. But the second test set which evidently coincides with your model 'live deployment' would be to predict on 'on-the-fly-generated-dataset' => this means you would feed the data real-time to your model.

The train-val-test split depends on how you want to create your model: how many time-steps you want to use(how many seconds to take into account when prediction the next step etc, how many variables you are trying to predict, how many time-steps ahead you want to predict(in your case 30 minutes would be 30*60 = 1800, since your dataset signals frequency is in seconds). It's a very broad question and refers more on how to create a dataset for time series analysis for multi-step prediction.